# Converting a column value from real data type to string during pattern matching in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL database named '**customer**' which has a column name called '**customer_no**' of datatype **real**. data contained in the '**customer_no**' column is as follows:

```
customer_no
........
........
54213154
11011011
11011012
11011013
11011014
11011215
11011015
11011101
45121478
........
........
```

I want to retrieve the column values that begin with 1101 using wildcard pattern matching. I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I have made the following SQL query to get the result:

```
select * from customer
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), customer_no) like '1101%';
```

But the problem is, I am getting 0 rows as output. Is there anything wrong in the above query? How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MS SQL Server @jarlh

Comment: I cannot think of any obvious reason that your query would not work.  That combined with your comment to @GordonLinhoff's answer leads me to believe that you have simplified your problem for posting here, but in doing so you may have done something that has fundamentally changed the nature of the problem (or even effectively removed it).  I would suggest restating your problem with a bit more of the real complexity.

Comment: What is the data type of customer number?  I suspect it is not a number and has leading spaces or something.

Comment: data type is real @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @user14216688 . . . Then my answer is probably the best approach.  And you should fix your data so you are not using floating point numbers as identifiers for anything.

Comment: I want to retrieve the results using pattern matching @Gordon Linoff

Comment: When the values are converted to a characters representation it's using scientific notation which is why the pattern doesn't match.

Comment: @user14216688 . . . You have a real problem with your data model if you want to do "pattern matching" on fuzzy values (yes, floating point numbers are *fuzzy*).  Fix the data model.  Store these numbers as integers, bigints, numerics, or strings.  But not floats.  That is wrong, and very, very, very wrong for anything that could be used in a `join` or `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

If customer number is an integer, why not use:

```
where customer_no >=  11010000 and
      customer_no <  11020000
```

Comment: I have shown a partial view of the table data. actually there are more data and I can't bind it within a range as you have shown. I want to derive the result using wildcard pattern matching. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @user14216688 I think that you should re-present your problem so that it is clear why Gordon's answer does not apply.  Gordon's answer can often be extended to a number of more complex real-world situations, but we cannot advise you on that because we do not know what the actual complexities of your situation are.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the real to numeric first

```
 CREATE TABLE #customer
 (
   customer_no real
 )

 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 54213154
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11011011
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11011012
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11011013
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11011014
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11011215
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11011015
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11011101
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 11021014
 INSERT INTO #customer(customer_no) SELECT 45121478

 SELECT * FROM #customer
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CONVERT(NUMERIC, customer_no)) like '1101%';

  DROP TABLE #customer
```

Answer (score 0):

When the values are converted to a characters representation it's using scientific notation which is why the pattern doesn't match.

Will math work?

```
where cast(floor(customer_no) as int) /
  cast(power(10, floor(log10(customer_no) - 3)) as int) = 1101
    -- note that floor(log10(1101)) = 3
```

The other advice you've gotten seems sound so this would really only apply if, for instance, the length of the id is variable. Using a floating point value for an id is only asking for headaches.